# How to create more than one demo import button in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on WordPress theme in which user has option to import demo data, It does import fine and goal is done. But, I have to provide user with two available options to select with, 1: family law, 2: injury law.

If user selects family law then demo content related to family law website will be imported and if user clicks on injury law drop down then content of injury law website will be imported. How can I achieve this in WordPress? Is it possible in WordPress or not?

Here is my import page code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Class Radium_Theme_Importer
 * @since 0.0.2
 */

 // Exit if accessed directly
 if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

 // Don't duplicate me!
 if ( !class_exists( 'Radium_Theme_Importer' ) ) {

    class Radium_Theme_Importer {

        /**
         * Set the theme framework in use
         */
        public $theme_options_framework = 'radium'; //supports radium framework and option tree

        /**
         * Holds a copy of the object for easy reference.
         *
         * @since 0.0.2
         *
         * @var object
         */
        public $theme_options_file;

        /**
         * Holds a copy of the object for easy reference.
         *
         * @since 0.0.2
         *
         * @var object
         */
        public $widgets;

        /**
         * Holds a copy of the object for easy reference.
         *
         * @since 0.0.2
         *
         * @var object
         */
        public $content_demo;

        /**
         * Flag imported to prevent duplicates
         *
         * @since 0.0.3
         *
         * @var array
         */
        public $flag_as_imported = array( 'content' => false, 'menus' => false, 'options' => false, 'widgets' =>false );

        /**
         * imported sections to prevent duplicates
         *
         * @since 0.0.3
         *
         * @var array
         */
        public $imported_demos = array();

        /**
         * Flag imported to prevent duplicates
         *
         * @since 0.0.3
         *
         * @var bool
         */
        public $add_admin_menu = true;

        /**
         * Holds a copy of the object for easy reference.
         *
         * @since 0.0.2
         *
         * @var object
         */
        private static $instance;

        /**
         * Constructor. Hooks all interactions to initialize the class.
         *
         * @since 0.0.2
         */
        public function __construct() {

            self::$instance = $this;

            $this->demo_files_path      = apply_filters('radium_theme_importer_demo_files_path', $this->demo_files_path);

            $this->theme_options_file   = apply_filters('radium_theme_importer_theme_options_file', $this->demo_files_path . $this->theme_options_file_name);

            $this->widgets              = apply_filters('radium_theme_importer_widgets_file', $this->demo_files_path . $this->widgets_file_name);

            $this->content_demo         = apply_filters('radium_theme_importer_content_demo_file', $this->demo_files_path . $this->content_demo_file_name);

            $this->imported_demos = get_option( 'radium_imported_demo' );

            if( $this->theme_options_framework == 'optiontree' ) {
                $this->theme_option_name = ot_options_id();
            }

            if( $this->add_admin_menu ) add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, 'add_admin') );

            add_filter( 'add_post_metadata', array( $this, 'check_previous_meta' ), 10, 5 );

            add_action( 'radium_import_end', array( $this, 'after_wp_importer' ) );

        }

        /**
         * Add Panel Page
         *
         * @since 0.0.2
         */
        public function add_admin() {

            add_submenu_page('themes.php', "Import Demo Data", "Import Demo Data", 'switch_themes', 'radium_demo_installer', array($this, 'demo_installer'));

        }

        /**
         * Avoids adding duplicate meta causing arrays in arrays from WP_importer
         *
         * @param null    $continue
         * @param unknown $post_id
         * @param unknown $meta_key
         * @param unknown $meta_value
         * @param unknown $unique
         *
         * @since 0.0.2
         *
         * @return
         */
        public function check_previous_meta( $continue, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique ) {

            $old_value = get_metadata( 'post', $post_id, $meta_key );

            if ( count( $old_value ) == 1 ) {

                if ( $old_value[0] === $meta_value ) {

                    return false;

                } elseif ( $old_value[0] !== $meta_value ) {

                    update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        /**
         * Add Panel Page
         *
         * @since 0.0.2
         */
        public function after_wp_importer() {

            do_action( 'radium_importer_after_content_import');

            update_option( 'radium_imported_demo', $this->flag_as_imported );
        }
        public function intro_html() {
            ?>

            <div style="background-color: #F5FAFD; margin:10px 0;padding: 5px 10px;color: #0C518F;border: 2px solid #CAE0F3; clear:both; width:90%; line-height:18px;">
                <p class="tie_message_hint">Importing demo data (post, pages, images, theme settings, ...) is the easiest way to setup your theme. It will
                allow you to quickly edit everything instead of creating content from scratch. When you import the data following things will happen:</p>

                  <ul style="padding-left: 20px;list-style-position: inside;list-style-type: square;}">
                      <li>No existing posts, pages, categories, images, custom post types or any other data will be deleted or modified .</li>
                      <li>No WordPress settings will be modified .</li>
                      <li>Posts, pages, some images, some widgets and menus will get imported .</li>
                      <li>Images will be downloaded from our server, these images are copyrighted and are for demo use only .</li>
                      <li>Please click import only once and wait, it can take a couple of minutes</li>
                  </ul>
             </div>

             <div style="background-color: #F5FAFD; margin:10px 0;padding: 5px 10px;color: #0C518F;border: 2px solid #CAE0F3; clear:both; width:90%; line-height:18px;"><p class="tie_message_hint">Before you begin, make sure all the required plugins are activated.</p></div>

             <?php

             if( !empty($this->imported_demos) ) { ?>

                <div style="background-color: #FAFFFB; margin:10px 0;padding: 5px 10px;color: #8AB38A;border: 2px solid #a1d3a2; clear:both; width:90%; line-height:18px;">
                    <p><?php _e('Demo already imported', 'radium'); ?></p>
                </div><?php
                //return;

              }
        }


        public function demo_installer() {

            $action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';

            if( !empty($this->imported_demos ) ) {

                $button_text = __('Import Again', 'radium');

            } else {

                $button_text = __('Import Demo Data', 'radium');

            }

            ?><div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"><br></div>
            <h2>Import Demo Data</h2>

           <div class="radium-importer-wrap" data-demo-id="1"  data-nonce="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('radium-demo-code'); ?>">

                <form method="post">
                    <?php $this->intro_html(); ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="demononce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('radium-demo-code'); ?>" />
                    <input name="reset" class="panel-save button-primary radium-import-start" type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_text ; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="demo-data" />

                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="radium-importer-message clear">
                        <?php if( 'demo-data' == $action && check_admin_referer('radium-demo-code' , 'demononce')){
                            $this->process_imports();
                        } ?>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>

            <br />
            <br /><?php

        }


        public function process_imports($mine = true, $content = true, $options = true, $widgets = true) {

            if ( $content && !empty( $this->content_demo ) && is_file( $this->content_demo ) ) {
                $this->set_demo_data( $this->content_demo );
            }

            if ( $options && !empty( $this->theme_options_file ) && is_file( $this->theme_options_file ) ) {
                $this->set_demo_theme_options( $this->theme_options_file );
            }

            if ( $options ) {
                $this->set_demo_menus();
            }

            if ( $widgets && !empty( $this->widgets ) && is_file( $this->widgets ) ) {
                $this->process_widget_import_file( $this->widgets );
            } 

            if($mine){
            $this->import_options();
            }

            do_action( 'radium_import_end');

        }

         /** Import Options Hook added by kami*/
        public function import_options() {
                //$data = $_POST['data'];
                $options_export = file_get_contents(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/framework/inc/theme-options/theme_options.txt');
                $data = $options_export;
                $data = base64_decode( $data );
                $data = json_decode( $data, true );

                if ( isset( $data ) ) {
                    foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
                        update_option( $key, wp_kses_post( stripcslashes( $value) ) );
                    }
                }

                die();
            }
            /** import action ends **/

        /**
         * add_widget_to_sidebar Import sidebars
         * @param  string $sidebar_slug    Sidebar slug to add widget
         * @param  string $widget_slug     Widget slug
         * @param  string $count_mod       position in sidebar
         * @param  array  $widget_settings widget settings
         *
         * @since 0.0.2
         *
         * @return null
         */
        public function add_widget_to_sidebar($sidebar_slug, $widget_slug, $count_mod, $widget_settings = array()){

            $sidebars_widgets = get_option('sidebars_widgets');

            if(!isset($sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_slug]))
               $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_slug] = array('_multiwidget' => 1);

            $newWidget = get_option('widget_'.$widget_slug);

            if(!is_array($newWidget))
                $newWidget = array();

            $count = count($newWidget)+1+$count_mod;
            $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_slug][] = $widget_slug.'-'.$count;

            $newWidget[$count] = $widget_settings;

            update_option('sidebars_widgets', $sidebars_widgets);
            update_option('widget_'.$widget_slug, $newWidget);

        }

        public function set_demo_data( $file ) {

            if ( !defined('WP_LOAD_IMPORTERS') ) define('WP_LOAD_IMPORTERS', true);

            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/import.php';

            $importer_error = false;

            if ( !class_exists( 'WP_Importer' ) ) {

                $class_wp_importer = ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-importer.php';

                if ( file_exists( $class_wp_importer ) ){

                    require_once($class_wp_importer);

                } else {

                    $importer_error = true;

                }

            }

            if ( !class_exists( 'WP_Import' ) ) {

                $class_wp_import = dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/wordpress-importer.php';

                if ( file_exists( $class_wp_import ) )
                    require_once($class_wp_import);
                else
                    $importer_error = true;

            }

            if($importer_error){

                die("Error on import");

            } else {

                if(!is_file( $file )){

                    echo "The XML file containing the dummy content is not available or could not be read .. You might want to try to set the file permission to chmod 755.<br/>If this doesn't work please use the Wordpress importer and import the XML file (should be located in your download .zip: Sample Content folder) manually ";

                } else {

                    $wp_import = new WP_Import();
                    $wp_import->fetch_attachments = true;
                    $wp_import->import( $file );
                    $this->flag_as_imported['content'] = true;

                }

            }

            do_action( 'radium_importer_after_theme_content_import');


        }

        public function set_demo_menus() {}

        public function set_demo_theme_options( $file ) {

            // Does the File exist?
            if ( file_exists( $file ) ) {

                // Get file contents and decode
                $data = file_get_contents( $file );

                if( $this->theme_options_framework == 'radium') {

                    //radium framework
                    $data = unserialize( trim($data, '###') );

                } elseif( $this->theme_options_framework == 'optiontree' ) {

                    //option tree import
                    $data = $this->optiontree_decode($data);

                    update_option( ot_options_id(), $data );

                    $this->flag_as_imported['options'] = true;

                } else {

                    //other frameworks
                    //$data = json_decode( $data, true );
                    $data = maybe_unserialize( $data );

                }

                // Only if there is data
                if ( !empty( $data ) || is_array( $data ) ) {

                    // Hook before import
                    $data = apply_filters( 'radium_theme_import_theme_options', $data );

                    update_option( $this->theme_option_name, $data );

                    $this->flag_as_imported['options'] = true;
                }

                do_action( 'radium_importer_after_theme_options_import', $this->demo_files_path );

            } else {

                wp_die(
                    __( 'Theme options Import file could not be found. Please try again.', 'radium' ),
                    '',
                    array( 'back_link' => true )
                );
            }

        }

        /**
         * Available widgets
         *
         * Gather site's widgets into array with ID base, name, etc.
         * Used by export and import functions.
         *
         * @since 0.0.2
         *
         * @global array $wp_registered_widget_updates
         * @return array Widget information
         */
        function available_widgets() {

            global $wp_registered_widget_controls;

            $widget_controls = $wp_registered_widget_controls;

            $available_widgets = array();

            foreach ( $widget_controls as $widget ) {

                if ( ! empty( $widget['id_base'] ) && ! isset( $available_widgets[$widget['id_base']] ) ) { // no dupes

                    $available_widgets[$widget['id_base']]['id_base'] = $widget['id_base'];
                    $available_widgets[$widget['id_base']]['name'] = $widget['name'];

                }

            }

            return apply_filters( 'radium_theme_import_widget_available_widgets', $available_widgets );

        }


        /**
         * Process import file
         *
         * This parses a file and triggers importation of its widgets.
         *
         * @since 0.0.2
         *
         * @param string $file Path to .wie file uploaded
         * @global string $widget_import_results
         */
        function process_widget_import_file( $file ) {

            // File exists?
            if ( ! file_exists( $file ) ) {
                wp_die(
                    __( 'Widget Import file could not be found. Please try again.', 'radium' ),
                    '',
                    array( 'back_link' => true )
                );
            }

            // Get file contents and decode
            $data = file_get_contents( $file );
            $data = json_decode( $data );

            // Delete import file
            //unlink( $file );

            // Import the widget data
            // Make results available for display on import/export page
            $this->widget_import_results = $this->import_widgets( $data );

        }


        /**
         * Import widget JSON data
         *
         * @since 0.0.2
         * @global array $wp_registered_sidebars
         * @param object $data JSON widget data from .json file
         * @return array Results array
         */
        public function import_widgets( $data ) {

            global $wp_registered_sidebars;

            // Have valid data?
            // If no data or could not decode
            if ( empty( $data ) || ! is_object( $data ) ) {
                return;
            }

            // Hook before import
            $data = apply_filters( 'radium_theme_import_widget_data', $data );

            // Get all available widgets site supports
            $available_widgets = $this->available_widgets();

            // Get all existing widget instances
            $widget_instances = array();
            foreach ( $available_widgets as $widget_data ) {
                $widget_instances[$widget_data['id_base']] = get_option( 'widget_' . $widget_data['id_base'] );
            }

            // Begin results
            $results = array();

            // Loop import data's sidebars
            foreach ( $data as $sidebar_id => $widgets ) {

                // Skip inactive widgets
                // (should not be in export file)
                if ( 'wp_inactive_widgets' == $sidebar_id ) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Check if sidebar is available on this site
                // Otherwise add widgets to inactive, and say so
                if ( isset( $wp_registered_sidebars[$sidebar_id] ) ) {
                    $sidebar_available = true;
                    $use_sidebar_id = $sidebar_id;
                    $sidebar_message_type = 'success';
                    $sidebar_message = '';
                } else {
                    $sidebar_available = false;
                    $use_sidebar_id = 'wp_inactive_widgets'; // add to inactive if sidebar does not exist in theme
                    $sidebar_message_type = 'error';
                    $sidebar_message = __( 'Sidebar does not exist in theme (using Inactive)', 'radium' );
                }

                // Result for sidebar
                $results[$sidebar_id]['name'] = ! empty( $wp_registered_sidebars[$sidebar_id]['name'] ) ? $wp_registered_sidebars[$sidebar_id]['name'] : $sidebar_id; // sidebar name if theme supports it; otherwise ID
                $results[$sidebar_id]['message_type'] = $sidebar_message_type;
                $results[$sidebar_id]['message'] = $sidebar_message;
                $results[$sidebar_id]['widgets'] = array();

                // Loop widgets
                foreach ( $widgets as $widget_instance_id => $widget ) {

                    $fail = false;

                    // Get id_base (remove -# from end) and instance ID number
                    $id_base = preg_replace( '/-[0-9]+$/', '', $widget_instance_id );
                    $instance_id_number = str_replace( $id_base . '-', '', $widget_instance_id );

                    // Does site support this widget?
                    if ( ! $fail && ! isset( $available_widgets[$id_base] ) ) {
                        $fail = true;
                        $widget_message_type = 'error';
                        $widget_message = __( 'Site does not support widget', 'radium' ); // explain why widget not imported
                    }

                    // Filter to modify settings before import
                    // Do before identical check because changes may make it identical to end result (such as URL replacements)
                    $widget = apply_filters( 'radium_theme_import_widget_settings', $widget );

                    // Does widget with identical settings already exist in same sidebar?
                    if ( ! $fail && isset( $widget_instances[$id_base] ) ) {

                        // Get existing widgets in this sidebar
                        $sidebars_widgets = get_option( 'sidebars_widgets' );
                        $sidebar_widgets = isset( $sidebars_widgets[$use_sidebar_id] ) ? $sidebars_widgets[$use_sidebar_id] : array(); // check Inactive if that's where will go

                        // Loop widgets with ID base
                        $single_widget_instances = ! empty( $widget_instances[$id_base] ) ? $widget_instances[$id_base] : array();
                        foreach ( $single_widget_instances as $check_id => $check_widget ) {

                            // Is widget in same sidebar and has identical settings?
                            if ( in_array( "$id_base-$check_id", $sidebar_widgets ) && (array) $widget == $check_widget ) {

                                $fail = true;
                                $widget_message_type = 'warning';
                                $widget_message = __( 'Widget already exists', 'radium' ); // explain why widget not imported

                                break;

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    // No failure
                    if ( ! $fail ) {

                        // Add widget instance
                        $single_widget_instances = get_option( 'widget_' . $id_base ); // all instances for that widget ID base, get fresh every time
                        $single_widget_instances = ! empty( $single_widget_instances ) ? $single_widget_instances : array( '_multiwidget' => 1 ); // start fresh if have to
                        $single_widget_instances[] = (array) $widget; // add it

                        // Get the key it was given
                        end( $single_widget_instances );
                        $new_instance_id_number = key( $single_widget_instances );

                        // If key is 0, make it 1
                        // When 0, an issue can occur where adding a widget causes data from other widget to load, and the widget doesn't stick (reload wipes it)
                        if ( '0' === strval( $new_instance_id_number ) ) {
                            $new_instance_id_number = 1;
                            $single_widget_instances[$new_instance_id_number] = $single_widget_instances[0];
                            unset( $single_widget_instances[0] );
                        }

                        // Move _multiwidget to end of array for uniformity
                        if ( isset( $single_widget_instances['_multiwidget'] ) ) {
                            $multiwidget = $single_widget_instances['_multiwidget'];
                            unset( $single_widget_instances['_multiwidget'] );
                            $single_widget_instances['_multiwidget'] = $multiwidget;
                        }

                        // Update option with new widget
                        update_option( 'widget_' . $id_base, $single_widget_instances );

                        // Assign widget instance to sidebar
                        $sidebars_widgets = get_option( 'sidebars_widgets' ); // which sidebars have which widgets, get fresh every time
                        $new_instance_id = $id_base . '-' . $new_instance_id_number; // use ID number from new widget instance
                        $sidebars_widgets[$use_sidebar_id][] = $new_instance_id; // add new instance to sidebar
                        update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', $sidebars_widgets ); // save the amended data

                        // Success message
                        if ( $sidebar_available ) {
                            $widget_message_type = 'success';
                            $widget_message = __( 'Imported', 'radium' );
                        } else {
                            $widget_message_type = 'warning';
                            $widget_message = __( 'Imported to Inactive', 'radium' );
                        }

                    }

                    // Result for widget instance
                    $results[$sidebar_id]['widgets'][$widget_instance_id]['name'] = isset( $available_widgets[$id_base]['name'] ) ? $available_widgets[$id_base]['name'] : $id_base; // widget name or ID if name not available (not supported by site)
                    $results[$sidebar_id]['widgets'][$widget_instance_id]['title'] = $widget->title ? $widget->title : __( 'No Title', 'radium' ); // show "No Title" if widget instance is untitled
                    $results[$sidebar_id]['widgets'][$widget_instance_id]['message_type'] = $widget_message_type;
                    $results[$sidebar_id]['widgets'][$widget_instance_id]['message'] = $widget_message;

                }

            }

            $this->flag_as_imported['widgets'] = true;

            // Hook after import
            do_action( 'radium_theme_import_widget_after_import' );

            // Return results
            return apply_filters( 'radium_theme_import_widget_results', $results );

        }

        /**
         * Helper function to return option tree decoded strings
         *
         * @return    string
         *
         * @access    public
         * @since     0.0.3
         * @updated   0.0.3.1
         */
        public function optiontree_decode( $value ) {

            $func = 'base64' . '_decode';
            $prepared_data = maybe_unserialize( $func( $value ) );

            return $prepared_data;

        }

    }//class

}//function_exists
```

?>

Comment: Quick guys it's important! :rolls eyes: - Yes it's possible with WordPress, the real question is what have you tried? Have your script set a parameter which tells the import process which button was clicked? Without knowing how your import process works, it's impossible for anyone to help.

Comment: ok let me provide you all my code in my question ...

Comment: code provided by now hope that provides you any hint